# glitchy access website, freezes for 30-60 sec intermittently

Tags: performance, ms-access, asp-classic, windows-server-2008, ado

asp website with access database freezes for 30-60 seconds intermittently. The site is on an internal 2008 server. About 25 users access the site simultaneously. Is it just the limits of access or can i do something to improve the situation? change any timeout/refresh settings anywhere? or could it be a problem with the network?

Comment: Are you keeping the connections to the database to a minimum by using getrows and such like?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you that no one is viewing data using a sql enterprise program ?

I have noticed that when you do a `select whatever from ...` query, and you do not commit the transaction (in the viewing program), you can have freezes when accessing the same database using a web site interface (like web pages using asp).

Please specify the database you are using, since that can make a difference.

Comment: Er, the original version of the question had ACCESS as a tag and ACCESS in the title. How much more specific about the database involved could he have been?